# In React with Redux, what does this snippet mean?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Joined a new team, and found below snippet:

```
const bookListContainer = (location, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], require => {
        cb(null, require('somepath').default)
    }, 'bookList')
}

<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="home" component={HomeComponent} />
    <Route path="bookList/:bookId" getComponent={bookListContainer} />
</Route>
```

what is the difference between `component` and `getComponent`? And for `bookListContainer`, what does it exact do? cannot understand `require.ensure()`

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to read code splitting: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html

You will learn some important concepts there to understand this code.

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to asynchronously load routes by splitting them into separate bundles.

`getComponent` will fire when the route is matched and consequently require what is necessary for that bundle `bookList`

This is a way to assist reducing the initial load time of your application.